# Fitting an object to an artboard in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, artboard

I can see how to fit an artboard to the art therein (Object -> Artboards -> Fit to selected art), but how do I do the opposite, i.e. how do I automatically resize a selected object to the artboard bounds?

[image: Example artwork extending beyond artboard bounds]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not "do the opposite".

There is **no** internal option to "fit artwork to artboard". What you are seeking does not exists.

You may be able to write or find a custom script for this though.

Comment: Thanks Scott - I'll just do it by sight rather than fretting about where the proper way to do it lives!

Answer (score 9):

If you press **Shift-o** then **Enter**
It will show you the width and height of the selected Artbord.

You can manually enter these dimensions to your object by first

**Selecting the object,** 
going to the **top toolbar** and clicking **transform**

You can then center it using the **Align to Artboard** settings.

Comment: It's a shame there isn't an option to transform while taking an objects stroke into consideration. This method is great, but if you've got a stroke it will exist outside of the artboard.

Comment: Classic adobe illustrator hiding useful features behind incompetent design.

Comment: @jkupczak super late reply I know, but do Object > Expand... and expand the stroke before scaling is the right way to handle this. Only catch is you can't adjust stroke anymore after you do this, but you can scale the inner/outer fill to adjust it.